# how to access data from remote local path in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app that will work locally to display videos from a dataset of 22Gb (among other things). Is there a way to tell shiny what local path should be used to access the videos? Using a soft link through the app's local www/ does not work. I want to avoid copying all data to the server's directory www/ directory.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question completely but isn't as pointing to any other object using the absolute path?

Comment: and I am not sure I understand your answer. using the absolute path does not work. what exactly is not clear? (so i can reformulate my question)

Comment: Are the videos stored on the same machine where you run your application?

Comment: the videos are in a remote file system, whose path is available from my machine, as any other path. They are outside of the shiny app path. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the answer to this is to use the `addResourcePath` 
function in shiny package

```
addResourcePath("videos/","/path_to_videos/")
```

and use `videos/` path when referring to any video file.

Comment: This did not work for me with 'slashes' in the path name. i.e. Replace 'videos/' with 'videos'. See: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/1529/files/fa791cd28cda1152722f5e879fdb281e70f05de6